# Make python ask questions from strings

Tags: python, string, list, random, input

I want to make python ask questions to the user - from random variables in lists. 
It needs to ask the question requiring an input from the user.

This is my code so far:

```
import time 
import random 
question = "0" 
score = "0" 
name = input("What is your full name?") 
print ("Hello " + name, "welcome to The Arithmetic Quiz") 
time.sleep(2) 
numbers = list(range(1, 50)) 
operators = ["+", "-", "*"] 
numbers1 = list(range(1,10)) 
print(str(random.choice(numbers)) + random.choice(operators) + str(random.choice(numbers1)))`
```

How would I make the last line of code ask a question and get an input from the user?

Also how would I make it so that python says whether this is correct when I do not know what python will ask?

Comment: Are you using python3.x? Why not use input as you did before? instead of printing last define it as i.e `number2` and then `answe =  input("what is" + numbers2)`

Comment: @hugohonorem I have now done this

Comment: See my edited answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is already in your code.

`user_input = input(str(random.choice(numbers)) + random.choice(operators) + str(random.choice(numbers)) + "? ")` should work.

It gets a sample random number from `numbers`, gets a random operator from `operators`, gets another random number from `numbers`, and stores the input to the variable `user_input`.

To get Python to check your answer, store the randomly generated arguments inside variables and check them. (If there is a better way of doing this, I would appreciate it if someone pointed it out to me).

```
operand1 = random.choice(numbers)
operand2 = random.choice(numbers)
operator = random.choice(operators)

if operator == '+':
    answer = operand1 + operand2
elif operator == '-':
    answer = operand1 - operand2
else:
    answer = operand1 * operand2

user_input = input(str(operand1) + operator + str(operand2) + "? ")

if str(answer) == user_input:
    print('Correct!')
else:
    print('Wrong!')
```

EDIT: [@mhawke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36031335/21945) has a better way of storing and manipulating the operands. Instead of storing the operators in a list, store them in a `dict` and map them to their corresponding operator function as so:

```
import operator

operators = {"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub, "*": operator.mul}
operand1 = random.choice(numbers)
operand2 = random.choice(numbers)
op = random.choice(operators)
expected_answer = op(operand1, operand2)
```

Documentation for [operator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html).

Comment: This says there is a "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'" this is for "answer = numbers * numbers1"

Comment: It's working for me. Where do you assign `numbers` and `numbers1`.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, how to determine whether the user entered the correct answer, you can store the randomly selected values and evaluate the resulting expression. Then compare that to the user's value:

```
import operator

operators = {"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub, "*": operator.mul}

operand1 = random.choice(numbers)
operand2 = random.choice(numbers1)
op = random.choice(operators)
expected_answer = op(operand1, operand2)

user_answer = input('{} {} {} = ?: '.format(operand1, op, operand2)
if int(user_answer) == expected_answer:
    print('Correct!')
else:
    print('Wrong. The correct answer is {}'.format(expected_answer)
```

The operators are stored in a dictionary. The operator tokens (+, -, *) are the keys in this dictionary, and the values are functions from the `operator` module that perform the operations. Using a dictionary like this is very flexible because if you wanted to support a new operator, e.g. division, you can just add it to the `operators` dictionary:

```
operators = {"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub, "*": operator.mul, '/': operators.div}
```

Comment: if int(user_answer == expected_answer): - the colon is said to be invalid syntax?

Comment: It should be `if int(user_answer) == expected_answer:`. Try debugging it for yourself.

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim: Thanks for picking up that typo.